# Add own image in OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am trying to implement an android application using maps. On a little research, I have narrowed down to either GoogleMaps or OpenStreetMap.

Since GoogleMaps doesn't allow us to save(cache) the maps offline, i have decided to use OpenStreetMap(OSM). But in that the satellite imagery can't be viewed after a zoom extent. So am planning to add my own images in OSM.

Is it possible to do so?

PS: This is know if it is feasible. I haven't started implementation yet.

Comment: OSM doesn't have any aerial images at all. Are you referring to the Bing aerials?

Comment: And please don't do crossposting: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34451/add-a-image-in-osm